# Can't knit PDF files in Spanish from RStudio (on Centos 7)

Tags: rstudio, r-markdown

I've been figthing a bit trying to create PDF files with RStudio in Spanish.

When I knit the document without any `lang` specification, everything works. This is a .Rmd file that renders without any issue:

**[test_file.Rmd]**

````
---
title: "Lorem ipsum test"
output:
  pdf_document: 
    toc: yes
  html_notebook: default
abstract: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi vel 
euismod metus."
---

# Lorem ipsum 1

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi vel euismod 
metus. Aenean molestie ligula ligula, imperdiet egestas tellus porttitor id. 
Aliquam feugiat ullamcorper consequat. Suspendisse non libero scelerisque metus 
sagittis placerat. Ut id tristique quam, ac tristique orci. 

```{r}
plot(cars)
```

# Lorem ipsum 2

Cras id pretium enim, sed bibendum dui. Curabitur turpis lacus, ultricies vitae 
sem vitae, interdum accumsan ligula. Donec quis ipsum pellentesque est ornare 
pretium sit amet eu libero. Fusce eget ante sed leo vestibulum placerat.
````

But when I include the `lang: es-MX` option, I get errors. I simply add the `lang: es-MX` option to the header (everything else is the same):

```
---
title: "Lorem ipsum test"
lang: "es-MX"
output:
  pdf_document: 
    toc: yes
  html_notebook: default
abstract: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi vel 
euismod metus."
---
```

And I get the following output in the R Markdown tab:

```
  |......................                                           |  33%
  ordinary text without R code

  |...........................................                      |  67%
label: unnamed-chunk-1


processing file: test_file.Rmd
  |.................................................................| 100%
  ordinary text without R code


/usr/lib/rstudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS test_file.utf8.md --to latex 
--from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash 
--output test_file.tex --table-of-contents --toc-depth 2 
--template /home/myuser/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.6/rmarkdown/rmd/latex/default-1.17.0.2.tex 
--highlight-style tango --latex-engine pdflatex --variable graphics=yes 
--variable 'geometry:margin=1in' --variable 'compact-title:yes' 
output file: test_file.knit.md

! Package babel Error: Language definition file shorthands=off.ldf not found.

Error: Failed to compile test_file.tex. See https://yihui.name/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. 
See test_file.log for more info.
Ejecución interrumpida
```

Checking the log file (`test_file.log`) I see only these warnings and errors:

```
[...]
Package babel Warning: No hyphenation patterns were loaded for
(babel)                the language `Spanish'
(babel)                I will use the patterns loaded for \language=0 instead.
[...]
! Package babel Error: Language definition file shorthands=off.ldf not found.

See the babel package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
[...]
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Now, I've found where the `.ldf` files live: `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel`, and there's no file named `off.ldf`.

So, my specific question is:
**How to get my PDF file from my .Rmd file *in Spanish*?**

I haven't found any solution, so... I'd appreciate any help.

---

#### Aditional info:

- R version: 3.6.0
- Platform: CentOS Linux 7 (64 bits)

---

#### Edit

As requested by Ralf Stubner in his comment, here's the "offending line" in the generated .tex file:

```latex
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
  \usepackage[shorthands=off,main=spanish]{babel} %% <- This is it!
\else
  \usepackage{polyglossia}
  \setmainlanguage[]{spanish}
\fi
```

I've found the template for this "offending" line at `/home/myuser/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.6/rmarkdown/rmd/latex/default-1.17.0.2.tex` (lines 82 and 83):

```latex
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
  \usepackage[shorthands=off,$for(babel-otherlangs)$$babel-otherlangs$,$endfor$main=$babel-lang$]{babel}
%%            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
%%            This is where I think the problem is
```

I tried commenting out this lines, and also removing that "shortnahds=off" bit, but errors keep popping out.

---

#### Edit 2

This is the header of the log file (test_file.log), which includes both TeX and TexLive version:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013) 
(format=pdflatex 2019.1.18)  21 AUG 2019 15:57
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test_file.tex
(./test_file.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, lo
aded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
```

According to this, TeX version is 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 and TexLive version is 2013. I've installed both using `yum` on Centos 7. Interestingly, when using LyX, everything works flawlessly.

Comment: Can you add `keep_tex: yes` to the YAML header at the same level as `toc: yes` and add the line from the resulting `tex` file  like `\usepackage[...]{babel}` to your question?

Comment: @RalfStubner Done! I also found where is the "source" of that "offending" line

Comment: The TeX code looks the way it should be. Which version of TeXlive do you have? How did you install it?

Comment: @RalfStubner I've added the version of both TeX and Tex Live to the question.

Comment: The log file shows that no Spanish hyphenation patterns have been loaded. I am not sure how one would change that with TeXLive 2013. Instead of investing time there I suggest installing a current TeX distribution. `tinytex::install_tinytex()` within R gives you a simple way to accomplish that. I am not sure if that will include Spanish by default, but if not, it will be easy to fix.

Comment: @RalfStubner Thank you! I'll install TinyTeX and come back to report if it worked or not.

Comment: @RalfStubner It worked! Thanks a lot. If you can, add an answer; I'd really like to up-vote it and accept it. As for the reason it didn't worked before, I simply can't find any explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log file shows that no Spanish hyphenation patterns have been loaded. I am not sure how one would change that with TeXLive 2013. Instead of investing time there I suggest installing a current TeX distribution. `tinytex::install_tinytex()` within R gives you a simple way to accomplish that. I am not sure if that will include Spanish by default, but if not, it will be easy to fix.